# Google Sheets, Listing all the items in a row and move to the next value when nothing matches

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I ran into a problem while working on my google sheets, what I would like to do is list all the items from the order based on the SKU (Vendor code) and then only move to the next OrderID if there is no more items for that certain Vendor.

[image: Order Breakdown is here]

Now this shows all the items of the order based on the orderID, and in the following picture I will show the Vendor sheet:
[image]

Would it be possible to list the orderID only when the SKU matches the vendors one, and then list all the items of that order only based on the SKU alone?

PS: I am using a GItHub script to export data from the Woocommerce

and here's a [Link](https://easyupload.io/s0fn6j) to the sample sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your "sample sheet" does not appear to be to a shared Google Sheet.
I'm not sure what you're doing but you should provide a shared link to a copy of your spreadsheet, with dummy data if necessary.
The shared link must allow edit priveleges to anyone, if you want to get the best help here.